# Joda Time Interval between two dates including time zone

Tags: jodatime

I use JodaTime library for time operations.
I have two dates:
Date One:

```
DateTime time_server = new DateTime(server_time_milisecs).
    withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Zurich"));  //+0100
```

Shows: `2013-01-27 13:44:42`

Date two:

```
DateTime time_local = new DateTime(DateTime.now()).
    withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());    //Have "Europe/Moscow" timezone  +0400
```

Shows: `2013-01-27 16:41:47`

**I need to find real interval including timezone**

```
Interval interval = new Interval(time_local, time_server);
Long.toString(interval.toDurationMillis()));
```

Result: 174040 miliseconds - **NOT CORRECT**

```
int secs = Seconds.secondsBetween(time_local,time_server).getSeconds();
```

Result: 174 secs **NOT CORRECT**

```
Period period = new Period(time_local, time_server);
Integer.toString(period.getSeconds()) //**Wrong too**
```

**Result must be: 10974 secs**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should spend some time (no pun intended) to grasp the Jodatime concepts ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653567/joda-whats-the-difference-between-period-interval-and-duration?rq=1)) if you need to do time calculations involving different timezones.

For example, consider the following code

```
DateTime nowHere = DateTime.now();
DateTime nowZur = nowHere.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Zurich"));
System.out.println("now Here:   " + nowHere );
System.out.println("now Zurich: " + nowZur  );
```

This outputs (for me, 4 hours offset from Zurich)  :

```
now Here:   2013-01-27T10:19:24.460-03:00
now Zurich: 2013-01-27T14:19:24.460+01:00
```

Pause and try to guess the output of the following lines:

```
Interval interv = new Interval(nowHere, nowZur);
System.out.println("Interval: " + interv.toDurationMillis());
```

The above prints `0` (zero). As it should.

Because `nowHere` and `nowZur` represent the **same instant of time** (in the physical line time), as represented in two different countries. They differ only in how they are represented, but physically they are the same time point (like `2.54 cm` and `1 in` are the same length, represented in two different forms).

Likewise, `2013-01-27T10:19:24.460-03:00` and `2013-01-27T14:19:24.460+01:00` are the same instant, the moment in which I run that code, only represented according the conventions of different countries; a martian could represent that same instant with his own martian calendar, and it would still be *the same instant*.

As those DateTimes represent the same time point, the physical interval (duration) between them must be zero. Now, if you want to get the "civil time difference" between the two, that's a wholly different thing. The `LocalDateTime` and the `Period` (totally different from `DateTime` and `Duration`) would then be the right concepts. For example:

```
Period per=new Period(nowHere.toLocalDateTime(),nowZur.toLocalDateTime());
System.out.println(per.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
```

This prints 14400 for me (4 "standard" -not physical- hours)

Comment: per.toStandardSeconds() throws a "Cannot convert to Seconds as this period contains months and months vary in length" exception if the two dates are some months away from each other. What should I use in that case?? I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: I have also tried to normalize the period using normalizedStandard() but I still get the same Exception.

Comment: @TiagoT Yours is not a comment about my answer, but a different question, you should post it as such.