# minus 1 hour to DateTime using Joda Time

Tags: java, swing, datetime, jodatime

I just want to subtract 1 hour from a `DateTime` I tried looking it up on Google and I found that there is a method called minus that takes a copy of the date and take a specific duration right here: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minus(long)

But I don't know how to use it and I can't an find a example on the internet.

Here's my code:

```
String string1 = (String) table_4.getValueAt(0, 1);
    String string2= (String) table_4.getValueAt(0, 2);

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm a").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTime dateTime1 = dtf.parseDateTime(string1.toString());
    DateTime dateTime2 = dtf.parseDateTime(string2.toString());

    final String oldf = ("hh:mm a");
    final String newf= ("hh.mm 0");
    final String newf2= ("hh.mm a");
    final String elapsedformat = ("hh.mm");

    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat(oldf);
    SimpleDateFormat format2E = new SimpleDateFormat(newf); 

    Period timePeriod = new Period(dateTime1, dateTime2);

    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()

     .appendHours().appendSuffix(".")
     .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("")
     .toFormatter();

    String elapsed = formatter.print(timePeriod);

    table_4.setValueAt(elapsed,0,3);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
    System.out.println(dateTime1);
    table_4.setValueAt("", 0, 4);
    table_4.setValueAt("", 0, 5);
```

Sample Data:

```
    dateTime1: 08:00 AM
    dateTime2: 05:00 PM
```

the period will be 9 hours. but i want it to be 8 hrs only because i want to subtract the lunch break in my program.

i tried it with this stupid code:

```
dateTime1.minus(-1)
```

I also tried parsing `string1` to double so I can subtract it by one.

```
double strindtoD = Integer.parseInt(string1);
```

I also tried making another `DateTime` and use period to get the difference of the two time

```
String stringOneHour = ("01:00 AM");
DateTime dateTime3 = dtf.parseDateTime(stringOneHour.toString());
Period timePeriod = new Period(dateTime3, dateTime1);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use:

```
dateTime.minusHours(1)
```

This is [documented in the API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusHours%28int%29).

**Note that `DateTime` objects are immutable**, so the operation alone has no effect. You need to assign the result of this method to a new object (or replace itself):

```
dateTime = dateTime.minusHours(1);
```

As to how to obtain a `Period` out of the difference between two `DateTime`s, you must first go through an `Interval`:

```
Period period = new Interval(begin, end).toPeriod();
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653567/joda-whats-the-difference-between-period-interval-and-duration) to a SO post explaining why there is both `Period` and `Interval`.

*Side note: Joda Time uses a LOT of indirections in its API; as such reading the Javadoc not only requires one to read the methods for one class, but also look at the list of inherited methods from all the inherited abstract classes/interfaces; for instance, a `DateTime` is also a `ReadableInstant`. One you get used to it, though, it's a breeze.*

Comment: Uhwhat? Sure it does. I use it and it works fine. There must be something else which you are not doing right... Note the immutability!

Comment: If you want an interval between two dates, Joda Time has `Interval`.

Comment: @JonSnow Good name for a `period`, bro.

Comment: @fge +1 for specifing DateTime objects are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of org.joda.time.DateTime then you can use minus(ReadablePeriod period) method like this

```
        Date date = LocalDate.now().minus(new Period(1, 0, 0, 0)).toDate();
```

where Period accepts int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int millis parameters

Answer (score -1):

By using Calender class object you can use this method to subtract hours.

`cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -numberOfHours);`

and also here is complete example [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-add-subtract-days-months-years-to-date-time-java.html)