# Make a date range in Joda Time without the year?

Tags: java, jodatime

Is it possible to make a range object similar to the Joda Time's Interval class where you can set a start and end date value but without including the year? For example, I would I like to do something in my code if a date is within the range August 1st and December 1st, regardless of the year.

Comment: Of course it's possible.  This should be fairly easy once you decide what the API looks like.  Have you tried anything?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yeah I've tried using the LocalDate class and the Interval class but they require a year parameter. And I'm going to be checking if a given local date is within that range, but if a year value is set, it may not work, because the years may be different.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm asking how this can be done in Joda Time. Is there a class or some function that will allow me to set a range without the year being involved. I can't find anything on SO or in its documentation addressing this problem.

Comment: You have to decide what you mean when a range includes the boundary between February and March. Is it 28 or 29 days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joda-Time provides a [`MonthDay`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/MonthDay.html) type that implements [`ReadablePartial`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadablePartial.html) (see the list of implementing classes for more types of partial times). You can combine this with [Guava's `Range`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained) type to represent a range of such intervals.

Joda-Time does not include a robust way to work with ranges of partials; your options for time-spans are [`Period`, `Interval`, and `Duration`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2653567/113632). I've found `Range` to be very suitable for such tasks, however.

Comment: I just tested this and it works when I test a range that does not overlap into a new year. However I need to be able to test for a range from September through the end of January and when I run the test it crashes where it initializes January 31st. Like this: `Range<MonthDay> mRegSeason = Range.closed(new MonthDay(9, 1), new MonthDay(1, 31));` Is there a work around or am I going to have to account for this with boilerplate code?

Comment: Well yes, January comes before September. `MonthDay` is an ordered type representing just months and days. If you want to incorporate years you'll need to use `LocalDate` or another date type.